# @Email not working but @pattern does in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to validate the spring form inputs using Hibernate.. When I try to use `@Email` for validating the email is does not return any message.. IF I use the `@Pattern`, its giving me the output however if try to validate "test@test.test" it accepts it.. I want to avoid accepting such entries.. Please guide in this matter..
This is my code :

Person.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="contact")
    private String contact;

    //@Email(message="Invalid")
    @Pattern(regexp ="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$", message="Invalid E-Mail")
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    //getter-setters
}
```

The messages.properties file:

```
 NotBlank.person.name = Name can not be empty
 NotBlank.person.address = Address can not be empty
 NotBlank.person.contact = Contact can not be empty
```

Comment: Why? From a pattern point of view `test@test.com` is a perfectly valid email address. Also your pattern is disallowing valid emails according to the specification for it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, your input `test@test.test` constitutes a valid email address as per the regex pattern used by Hibernate Email Validator. You can take a look at the source code of Hibernate's `AbstractEmailValidator` [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.java).

In fact this input will be considered a valid email by most email validators. However, for your needs it is an invalid email maybe because it has 4 characters after the last dot, you can use the pattern you have shown in your question.

Comment: These days you are allowed to have 4 characters after the last dot - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, I agree. That's why I am saying that OP's input will be considered valid by most email validators.